# Big O Notation/Time Complexity issue

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

Would a recursive method call that is recursively called n times (but does not occur in a for loop) and only contains if/else statements within the method be considered O(N) or O(1)? Thanks!

Comment: recursion is pretty much the same as loop, so O(N)

Comment: If `n` doubles, what happens to the number of recursions? Double: _O(n)_, Stay the same: _O(1)_, Quadruple: _O(n^2)_. It is really that simple.

Comment: "called N times": so what ever is in it has to be done N times, right? How would you do that in O(1)?

Comment: Does the same amount of work happen for n=1 as for b=1,000,000? For instance, does it result in the same number of method invocations? If not, you can at least rule out O(1). Your question is a tad unclear to me, but it sounds like it's probably O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be `O(N)`.

The general approach to doing complexity analysis is to look for all significant constant-time executable statements or expressions (like comparisons, arithmetic operations, method calls, assignments) and work out an algebraic formula giving the number of times that they occur.  Then reduce that formula to the equivalent big O complexity class.

In your case, method calls are significant.

When you have some experience at doing this, you will be able to leave out statements that "obviously" don't contribute to the overall complexity.  But to start with, it is a good exercise to count *everything*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of factorial code in python. The recursion is pretty much the same as looping, here we are calling factorial function again and again until the if condition satisfies which is same in the loops. so O(N)

```
def factorial( n ):
   if n <1:   # base case
       return 1
   else:
       returnNumber = n * factorial( n - 1 )  # recursive call
       print(str(n) + '! = ' + str(returnNumber))
       return returnNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate time complexity, there are 3 types-
1) Best case 
2) Worst case
3) Average case

As, you are wrote O(n) it means you are checking for worst case time complexity, which would be **O(n)** as, we will take account the block in which recursion is present as the worst case.
If you are looking for best case you can take it as **O(1)** as it might not get into recursion according to the if-else condition.